# Orderdict is not defined in django template when using in js

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have implemented nested serailizer via djangorestframework. I am sending the variable as a context in my django template.
I struck with a problem while using template variable inside `<script>` tag it is showing an error that

> Error: Orderdict is not defined

```
var data = {{ data.companies|safe }};
```

what i get after rendering was

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 4), ('name', 'axis'), ('acronym', 'axis'), ('growth', [OrderedDict([('datetime', '2007-11-30T00:00:00+05:30'), ('_close', 224.199997)]), OrderedDict([('datetime', '2007-12-31T00:00:00+05:30'), ('_close', 169.125)]), OrderedDict([('datetime', '2008-01-31T00:00:00+05:30'), ('_close', 160.024994)]), OrderedDict([('datetime', '2008-02-29T00:00:00+05:30'), ('_close', 123.199997)]), OrderedDict([('datetime', '2008-03-31T00:00:00+05:30'), ('_close', 155.300003)]), OrderedDict([('datetime', '2008-04-30T00:00:00+05:30'), ('_close', 140.300003)]), OrderedDict([('datetime', '2008-05-31T00:00:00+05:30'), ('_close', 112.074997)]), OrderedDict([('datetime', '2008-06-30T00:00:00+05:30'), ('_close', 99.224998)]),.....]
```

So as Orderdict is not a valid thing in `JS` but it is rendering as such.
**How can i solve this?** I have also tried `escapejs` filter but no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass data from Python to JS like that. You need to convert it to JSON in your view first.

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: I have used serialised data wasn't that supposed to be JSON.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. JSON is the way to serialise data so that you can pass it between Python and JavaScript.